# Finding duration of events in sql database

Tags: sql, datetime, time, sybase, duration

In Sybase, I have a set of datetimes and status. I'm trying to figure out how much time was 'on' and how much time was 'off'.

```
table

id          time                status
123456789   01/01/14 03:25 PM   off
123466376   01/01/14 11:35 PM   on
123475437   01/02/14 02:50 AM   on
123481237   01/02/14 10:19 AM   on
123481565   01/02/14 03:20 PM   on
123490893   01/03/14 03:05 PM   off
123498583   01/03/14 06:58 PM   off
123502793   01/04/14 08:47 AM   off
123505238   01/04/14 06:21 PM   on
123508001   01/05/14 12:31 AM   off
123515817   01/05/14 09:43 PM   on
123519023   01/05/14 10:21 PM   on
123528892   01/06/14 05:47 AM   on
123541640   01/06/14 05:25 PM   on
123544143   01/07/14 10:10 AM   on
123553495   01/07/14 06:29 PM   off
123558775   01/08/14 04:40 PM   off
123566262   01/09/14 02:41 AM   on    
...
```

Hundreds of thousands of line like this. Times and ids are growing, but not sequential.

I have a feeling I have to check which events are the first on, create a table of just those, and then find the lowest time after that's off. However, that sounds rather intensive. Is there some function or well known method of sussing this data out?

Comment: Hello, can you give more details. What do the id's represent, your list of id's are unique, should an id start off as on and the it changes state to off?

Comment: The service polls the status at semi-random intervals. The id is not really important, but it grows over time, semi-randomly. There's more data in the table, but this is all I can use.